# Solid method for executing PHP on JS call?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, shell

I know I can use AJAX to call and modify HTML within JS code. But what if I want to execute a command on the server using PHP like `exec($command, $result);`? What is the best method for calling PHP from a JS to run stuff on the server?

I was thinking about creating a huge switch matrix that submits forms on the JS side, and then another switch on the PHP side to intercept the submissions - and have all those forms in the HTML be hidden - but that sounds like overkill to me. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE/SOLUTION**

I used the following JS code:

```
function myOnFocus() {
    var myInput= document.getElementById("myInputID");
    $.ajax({ url: '',
        data: {
            "action" : "myActionName", 
            "myInputValue"       : $('#myInputID').val(), 
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    });
}
```

And in the PHP I used:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch($action) {
        case 'myActionName' : 
            $myInputValue         = $_POST["myInputValue"];
            $command = "--my-server-command/file-that-i-needed-to-run 2>&1";
            exec($command, $results);
            echo " \n".implode($results);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Just use ajax and submit a form to a php page. Then, PHP echos your result, keep working with JS.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: But it is not a form I want to submit. I want to execute a script on the server if a user clicks inside an input `onFocus` for example. And I do try to avoid doing a massive switching system for multiple server calls.

Comment: You still submit a form through ajax. There is no other, easier, choice (or else everyone would probably be using that)

Comment: You can submit a form through JavaScript, if you target it to a hidden iframe then it is ajax. If you gather the data from the form and then send it through XMLHttpRequest (instead of submitting the form) then it is Ajax. (And there are a couple of other Ajax techniques like JSONP out there too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know I can use AJAX to call and modify HTML within JS code.

No. You can use DOM for that.

Ajax is used to make HTTP requests and process HTTP responses from JavaScript.

You can combine them to get data from the server using Ajax and then use DOM to insert that data into the page.

> But what if I want to execute a command on the server using PHP

If you want to do anything in PHP and trigger it from a browser then you need to make an HTTP request.

> What is the best method for calling PHP from a JS to run stuff on the server?

If you don't want to load a new page, then Ajax.

If you want to load a new page, then setting `location` to a new URL (if you want to make a GET request) or submitting a form (if you want to make a POST request or are using a form to gather the data from the user in the first place) are the usual methods.

Comment: ^ for showing him he knows nothing. You just shattered his delusions of knowledge, I like that. Good Job!

Comment: @MrJack Is your source for existence here is to bash at people who know less than you? Or it is a mere need for empowerment over others?

Comment: Actually, I am not the one who shattered those delusions, now, am I? If I would be here for that, I would only go through any post that claims to know something and then answer them telling them that they are wrong. It was a perfect demonstration of the term that our knowledge is just an illusion, I only applaud that, when I see it.

Comment: Point is, @Quentin did not shatter anything. They only addressed several issues in a very much `list` list manner and added explanation to each issue at hand. While you came along and just trying to sound like a jack's bottom...

Comment: Although I am facing a different issue. The submission stays in a loop as long as I stay inFocus - even without touching the mouse/keyboard. How can I force it not resubmitting?